# SPARQL: extract the dbo class for each result

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have a DBpedia request that give me a label, a Dpedia URI and the corresponding wikipedia link. I want to add a column to get the dbo class of each line. Can any one help me please?

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
select distinct  ?Nom ?resource ?url ?p
 where {  
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   ?resource rdf:type ?p
   FILTER(regex(?p,"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"))
   FILTER ( langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
   ?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you have the solution, then you should post it as an answer and then mark it as accepted so that it is easier for others looking for the solution.

Secondly, I feel that the solution you came up would work but is not the right way to do it. For getting `dbo:` types, one should query for types that are `owl:Class` types.

This is how I would do it

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
select distinct  ?Nom ?resource ?url ?p
 where {  
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom ;
      foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url ;
      a ?p .
   ?p a owl:Class .
   FILTER ( langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
   ?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
   } limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by:

> get the dbo class of each line.

But if you mean to get all predicates related to each row, the following query may help. I limited them to English ones to see the results better.

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select distinct  ?Nom ?resource ?url ?p
 where {  
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
?resource ?p ?dbo.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
FILTER ( langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )).
?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
FILTER langMatches( lang(?Nom), "en" ) 

}
limit 100
```

Comment: No that's not what i want. what i want is to get only the rdf:Type on dbo classification, meaning when rdf:type = dbo:... For example, for the resource http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple_Inc. , i need to get dbo:company, for the resource http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple i need dbo:Plant.

Comment: @Adem: 
So you can write: 
?resource rdf:type ?p. 
Then ?p is the type of resource